# Can't login into phpMyAdmin with Safari

Tags: macos, mac, safari, phpmyadmin

I have this weird problem that I can't login into phpMyAdmin with Safari. With every other system/browser I can login just fine, but not with my Safari browser. I tried to empty cache, history, etc., but nothing helps. Any solutions?

Comment: "can't login" isn't really a detailed enough error description.

Answer (score 0):

Open your config.inc.php file and add or uncomment this line:

```
$cfg['AllowThirdPartyFraming'] = true;
```

Restart the services and try again.

Comment: nope doesn't work. the problem is @ safari i guess cause other browsers and laptops can acces the server and I can also access it with ssh etc.